# Getting function from model and putting it to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Django project. I have model and serializer and I'm trying to send the result of my function "increase_id" from model to serializer. What I'm doing wrong? How I can to implement it?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    first_field = models.CharField()
    second_name = models.CharField()
    
    def increase_id(self):
        own_id = self.id
        magnifier = own_id + 50_000
        return magnifier
```

serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    magnifier = serializers.IntegerField(source='increase_id')
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'age', 'magnifier')
```

Answer (score 1):

The above method will work well when you are fetching details but in the case of creation, it will give an error that magnifier field is required.

You can use property decorator

```
class Person(models.Model):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    first_field = models.CharField()
    second_name = models.CharField()

@property
def increase_id(self):
    own_id = self.id
    magnifier = own_id + 50_000
    return magnifier



class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    magnifier = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_magnifier(self, instance):
        return self.increase_id

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'age', 'magnifier')`
```